# How to apply git patch on repository with changed history?

Tags: git, git-patch

Recently i migradted from SVN to git and my team already started to work in fresh git repository.

Later i discovered some problems with conversion and made the 2nd git repo from SVN with some fixes and history rewrites.

Now i have 2nd git copy of SVN repo (whicn i am satisdied with) and i want to patch it with changes which were already made with my team in 1st git repository.

For such purposes i try to use git patches:

- `git-format-patch --zero-commit --stdout > master.patch` to create
  single file of changes which were already made to `master` of 1st git
  repo
- and `git-am` to apply commits from `*.patch` file  on `master`
  of 2nd repository

I specify `--zero-commit`, because hashes in patch file will be wrong, sicne i actually have two different repositories.

The problem is that when i try to apply patch with `git am master.patch` i get:

> Applying: %commit_name% error: patch failed:
>   readme.md:5 error: readme.md: patch
>   does not apply Patch failed at 0001 %commit_name% The copy of the patch
>   that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch When you have
>   resolved this problem, run "git am --continue". If you prefer to skip
>   this patch, run "git am --skip" instead. To restore the original
>   branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".

even when i have only one commit in this patch and i want to apply it on the same repo to get the same commit, but on another branch.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding `--ignore-whitespace` to `git am` solved the main problem, but i still has warnigs like:

> .git/rebase-apply/patch:56: trailing
>
> warning: squelched 9 whitespace
>
> errors warning: 14 lines add whitespace errors.